# In ASP.NET Core, does CacheItemPriority set to NeverRemove actually do that?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

In previous versions of asp.net, NeverRemove was only a strong recommendation to the cache engine. If there was not enough system memory, it would be removed anyhow.  Is this the case in ASP.NET Core?  In the docs it says that NeverRemove should be used for testing because the cache will never be removed.

Is this true? I could not find the source code for this in the repo.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on cache provider.

If you are talking about `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory` - yes, cache items with priority `NeverRemove` are not candidates for memory compacting ([MemoryCache.cs source, line 401](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/9db2c381b19ff2aeb8d6783f145c3c41e1529b78/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCache.cs#L401))

Comment: Dmitry, if the IIS server has an idle timeout setting set to 20 minutes, does `CacheItemPriority.NeverRemove` ensure that the cache does not get removed in the event that the application goes into a _sleep_ state?